# browse local S3 storage (not Amazon) with command line tool

Tags: command-line, rhel, storage, amazon-s3

I wish to browse, put and get files in local S3 storage from vendor [EMC Atmos Cloud Storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EMC_Atmos)

I have a RHEL7 and wish to do it on command line. We have no flat structure (like Amazon) we use directories.

With a search engine I found [Amazon S3 Tools: Command Line S3 Client Software and S3 Backup](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd).

Howto point `s3cmd` to a local S3 host?

Answer (score 1):

[s3cmd-howto](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd-howto) should help you, you can run commands like:

`s3cmd ls s3://logix.cz-test`

`s3cmd put addressbook.xml s3://logix.cz-test/addrbook.xml`

Answer (score 0):

I am doing this. To generalize scripts, I have chosen to configure s3cmd via .s3cmd file located in script-runnning accounts home directory.

```
[Default]
access_key = Backup:*****************************
host_base = <hostname>:<port>
host_bucket = <hostname>:<port>
secret_key = ************************************
signature_v2 = True
```

I use a local NAS for S3 storage, and the api only supports signature_v2, which is set to False as default.

I have tested this with the current s3cmd version 2.1.0 on CentOS 7 and QNAP NAS flashed to firmware 4.2.6 build 20200821